# Ошибка при построении, когда объявляю переменную шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

Написал Шаблонный класс. Компилируется нормально. 
Как только в исполняющей функции объявляю что данные этого типа, то вылетает ошибка:

> 1>Бинарное дерево(1 вариант).obj :
> error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный
> внешний символ "public: **thiscall
> BinVector<int>::BinVector<int>(void)"
> (??0?$BinVector@H@@QAE@XZ) в функции
> _main 1>Бинарное дерево(1 вариант).obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на
> неразрешенный внешний символ "public:**
> thiscall BinVector<int>::~BinVector<int>(void)"
> (??1?$BinVector@H@@QAE@XZ) в функции
> _main

Почему так? не могу понять(
описал же правильно, вроде..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BinVector.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BinVector<int> M;
    return 0;
}
```

заголовок шаблона

```
#pragma once

template<class T>
class BinVector
{
    int len;
    class Element 
    {
        T list;
        int left,right;
        Element(T t){list=t;left=-1;right=-1;}
    };
    Element* Arr, BUF;
    void changeNombers(T t,int N=0);

public:
    BinVector();
    ~BinVector();
    T &operator [](int N);
    void push_back(T t);
    void pop(int N=len-1);
    void pop_back(){pop();}
};
```

.срр

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BinVector.h"

template<class T>
BinVector<T>::BinVector(){len=0;};

template<class T>
BinVector<T>::~BinVector(){};

template<class T>
void BinVector<T>::push_back(T t)
{
    BUF=new Element[++len];
    for(int i=0; i<len-1)
        BUF[i]=Arr[i];
    BUF[len-1]=t;
    delete Arr;
    Arr=BUF;
    if(len==0) return;//первому элементу указателей не надо.
    changeNombers(t);

    return;
}

template<class T>
void BinVector<T>::pop(int N)
{
    bool b=false;
    BUF=new Element[--len];
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    { 
        if(i==N)(b=true);
        BUF[i]=Arr[i+int(b)];
    }
    Element buf=BUF;
    int LEN=len;
    for(int i=0;i<LEN;i++)
        push_back(buf[i]);

    return;
}

template<class T>
void BinVector<T>::changeNombers(T t,int N/*=0*/)
{
    if (t<=Arr[N].list)
        if(Arr[N].left==-1) Arr[N].left=len-1;
        else changeNombers(t, Arr[N].left);
    else 
        if(Arr[N].right==-1) Arr[N].right=len-1;
        else changeNombers(t, Arr[N].right);
        return;
}

template<class T>
T &BinVector<T>::operator [](int N)
{
    if(N>=len||N<0) sleep(100000);
    return Arr[N].list;
};
```

Comment: ошибка номер 1:
реализация шаблонов должна быть в `*.h а не *.cpp`

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, это не исправило ошибку...

а почему реализация должна быть в *.h?

Comment: @andrw: Потому что шаблоны не компилируются. Шаблоны в C++ — не что иное, как продвинутый вариант макросов. Во время компиляции `.cpp` с шаблоном компилятор не знает, с каким параметром будет этот шаблон проинстанциирован, и, соответственно, не может его скомпилировать.

Могу поспорить, когда вы перенесли реализацию шаблонов в `.cpp`, старая ошибка исчезла.

Comment: @VladD, с вами опасно спорить! да, исчезла.

А описывать функции надо в нутри класса или достаточно просто скопировать из *.cpp  B *.h?

Comment: @andrw: как вам больше нравится, в принципе, компилятору всё равно. Я обычно оставляю описания функций вне класса, чтобы выглядело похоже на обычный класс, но это исключительно вопрос личных предпочтений.

Comment: @VladD, Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Надо явно инстанцировать шаблоны для нужных типов в `.cpp` файле, чтобы это заработало. Если этого не сделать, то определения функций не генерируются и линкер, соответственно, не может их найти.

В данном случае вы используете `BinVector<int> M;` в `main.cpp`, значит, и явная инстанциация должна быть для `int` в `BinVector.cpp`.

Синтаксис для явной инстанциации можно посмотреть в доках https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template.